# vertically centering modal window/div on ipad

Tags: jquery, ipad, modal-dialog

I've found a very basic modal window script that's working well on all browsers including the iPad. However, on the iPad it positions the modal window at the top of the site so if the user has scrolled to the bottom of the site, he's unable to see it without scrolling upwards.

I thought something like this might help:

```
    //Get the window height and width
    var winH = $(window).height();
    var winW = $(window).width();

    if (navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i)) {
    winH = winH + $(window).scrollTop();
    } 

    //Set the popup window to center
    $(id).css('top',  winH/2-$(id).height()/2);
    $(id).css('left', winW/2-$(id).width()/2);
```

But it's not working in that it still positions the div incorrectly, ie. not in the viewport.

Any suggestions much appreciated!

Comment: See my answer below related to `position:fixed`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the issue is iPad's dislike for position: fixed. This is how I got around it:

```
if (navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i)) {
var positionY = window.pageYOffset;
boxH = 690 - 400; 
// 690 is Safari's usable area on ipad landscape
// 400 is height of div
positionM = positionY + boxH;
//Set the popup window to center
$(id).css('top', positionM);
}
```

Obviously it doesn't vertically center the div on portrait iPad, but hey this is good enough, frankly!

Answer (score 2):

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j969k/1/) that'll get you to where you need to be. (Pay attention to the positon: fixed in the css).  Basically, all you need to do is give your modal a fixed position, top margin 50%, left margin 50%, and then offset top/left by 50% of your modal height/width repectively.

This will, of course, break down in earlier versions of IE (issues with the 'fixed' attribute)...but then again, your average iPad user probably isn't rolling [IE6](http://ie6update.com/), anyway.

```
.sample{
       position   :  fixed;
       top        :  50%;
       left       :  50%;
       height     :  100px;
       width      :  100px;           
       margin-left:  -50px;
       margin-top :  -50px;
       border     :  1px solid #000
}

<div class="sample">Sample</div>
```

Comment: thanks for the css - i much prefer that over the jquery, but it's still not centering vertically on the ipad. it centers, but in the top 768px.